# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'int'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, object, fluttermap

I am trying to add a BottomNavigationBarItem and give it a different icon and label.
then I tried to change the pages when you click on them:
but it gives me three message errors:

```
The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'int'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.
```

When I searched for the solution I have known that it is an sdk-type issue but couldn't know how to solve it without changing the sdk
I am kind of new in flutter

```
class _TaskscreenState extends State<Taskscreen> {
  List<Map<String, Object>> get _pages => [
    {
      'page': provincesScreen(),
      'title': 'org',
    },
    {
      'page': FavouritScreen(),
      'title': 'your favourits',
    },
  ];

  int _selectedpageIndex = 0;
  void _selectedPage(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedpageIndex = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
          AppBar(title: Text(_pages[_selectedpageIndex['title']])),
      body:_pages[_selectedpageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectedPage,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.purple,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: _selectedpageIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            label: ('categories'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            label: ('favourites'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            label: ('Rating'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `_selectedpageIndex['title']` won't work because `_selectedpageIndex` is an `int` (as the error tells you). You probably want `_pages[_selectedpageIndex]['title']` (ie the same way as you access `_pages[_selectedpageIndex]['page']`)

Comment: The error is existing in both line the appbar and the body. but I have changed as you said, one message error has gone but still get this: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. in both appbar and body

Comment: Well, you are not caring about types at all. You define `pages` as a `List<Map<String, Object>>` (probably because you want to put data of different types in there). So `_pages[_selectedpagedIndex]` is a `Map<String, Object>`. And when you do `_pages[_selectedpagedIndex]['title']` you select one `Object` of this `Map`. But you try to assign that `Object` to a `String` which isn't possible, because the compiler can't know, that the title is actually `String`, so you have to tell the compiler, it's a `String` like follows `_pages[_selectedpagedIndex]['title'] as String`

Comment: I understand the error more now , this worked for me thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you put this wrong

```
  AppBar(title: Text(_pages[_selectedpageIndex['title']])),
```

correct it to:

```
  AppBar(title: Text(_pages[_selectedpageIndex]['title'])),
```